# Are there any groups $G$ for which there exist non-trivial subgroups $H \leq G$ with $G\setminus H\cup\{1\} \leq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I could prove that such a group $G$ needs to contain a non-trivial self-inverse element, however, I could not find an example of such a group $G$. Is there any example of one or could I simply not disprove the existence of one for a more general case (one where no non-trivial elements are self-inverse)?

Comment: What do you mean by $H\cup\{1\}$? Subgroups also have identities?

Comment: @DonThousand I think it's $(G\setminus H)\cup \{1\}$.

Comment: @Arthur Ohhhh that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Take an element $g\notin H$. Note that for any $h\in H$, we have $hg\notin H$. If we let $h$ be a non-identity element, $hg\cdot g^{-1}=h$ is a non-identity element of $H$. This proves that multiplication in your subset is not closed, except in trivial cases (where "trivial" implies that either $g$ or $h$ as required does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Pick $g\in G\setminus H$ and $h\in H\setminus \{1\}$. Then $g^{-1}$ and $gh$ are $\in G\setminus H$, but their product $h$ is not in $G\setminus H\cup\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. In general if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups then $G_1\cup G_2$ is a group if and only if $G_1\subseteq G_2$ or $G_2\subseteq G_1$. So in your case we would get $H\subseteq (G\setminus H)\cup\{e\}$ or $(G\setminus H)\subseteq H$. This is possible only when one of the groups is $\{e\}$.